# Is JWT claim name case-sensitive?

Tags: http, security, oauth, jwt

Simple question:

Is following payload:

```
{
    "aud": ["aud1", "aud2"]
}
```

equivalent to:?

```
{
    "AUD": ["aud1", "aud2"]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [specification in RFC7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-10.1.1) claim names are case-sensitive:

> **Claim Name**:
> The name requested (e.g., "iss"). ...  This name is
> case sensitive.  Names may not match other registered names in a
> case-insensitive manner unless the Designated Experts state that
> there is a compelling reason to allow an exception.